# Binding Source is empty

Tags: c#, winforms

My DataSet (CafeDataSet) is in the project `Cafe.DataAccess` and my winforms are in another project `Cafe.FrontEnd`. `Cafe.DataAccess` is being compiled as DLL and its reference is added in `Cafe.FrontEnd`

I can show data in a combobox using code below

```
comboBox1.DataSource = userTableAdapter.GetUsers();
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
comboBox1.ValueMember = "Id";
```

GetUsers is the method I created in UserTableAdapter to return all users.

But when I try to bind comboBox1 with the *Object Data Source* `CafeDataSet` from `Cafe.DataAccess` through Add Project Data source wizard, it is empty.

Why? How to solve this? I want to keep dataset in separate project as it is now.

Answer (score 0):

You still need to call userTableAdapter.GetUsers() somewhere in your Cafe.FrontEnd to populate the local dataset field of type CafeDataSet that the comboBox1 is bound to. (I'm not sure I understand what you did though. Did you use a BindingSource?)

Comment: Normally if I drag drop a datagrid from Data Sources window, I don't need to code that GetUsers() to populate datagridview.